# Syntax highlighter bugs on multiple <script> tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

To illustrate, multiple non-`script` tags works fine:

```
<element name="value"></element>
<element name="value"></element>
```

But multiple `script` tags bugs the highlighter, see the pattern:

```
<script name="value"></script>
<script name="value"></script>
```

and

```
<script name="value"></script>
<script name="value"></script>
<script name="value"></script>
```

and

```
<script name="value"></script>
<script name="value"></script>
<script name="value"></script>
<script name="value"></script>
```

here's a real world example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/one.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/two.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                alert('waa');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Look like a bug in some sort of XSS filter, if any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed at revision 92: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/detail?r=92

Comment: Yes, the upgrade has happened. The scripts looks better now :) Thanks.